# D3 - How to access fresh data in drag functions

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have 5 group elements on a line which i can drag them across that line.

On drag end i save the position of the current element in my data object. Afterwards if i drag another element, the data array seems to not been updated. Everytime in drag function I see the initial state of data.

Enter, update, exit

```
const settingsData = settings.map(({ day, ...rest }) => ({ x: scale(day), y: 50, ...rest}));

const group = d3.select('svg').selectAll(".handlersGroup").data(settingsData, ({ id }) => id);

    group.exit().remove();

    const itemGroup = group.enter().append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0, 0)')
    .attr('class', 'handlersGroup');

    itemGroup.append('circle')
      .attr("r", 14)
      .attr("cy", d => d.y)
      .attr("cx", d => d.x)
      .style("fill", ({ color }) => color);

    itemGroup.append('text')
      .attr("y", d => d.y - 15)
      .attr("x", d => d.x + 10)
      .style("fill", 'black')
      .style('opacity', 0)
      .text(d => `${d.type} - ${Math.round(scale.invert(d.x))}`);

    itemGroup.merge(group);

    itemGroup
    .call(drag)
    .on('mouseover', function () {
      d3.select(this).select('text').style('opacity', 1);
    })
    .on('mouseout', function () {
      d3.select(this).select('text').style('opacity', 0);
    });
```

Drag function

```
const drag = d3.drag()
      .on('drag', function(d) {
        const currentX = d3.event.x;

        const validatedX = currentX < 37 ?
        d.x : currentX > width - 30 ?
        d.x : currentX;

        const startingTextCorrectionPoint = 500;
        const moveAdditional = currentX > startingTextCorrectionPoint ? (currentX - startingTextCorrectionPoint) : 0;

        d3.select(this).select("text").attr("x", d.x = validatedX - moveAdditional + 10);
        d3.select(this).select('text').text((i) => `${d.type} - ${Math.round(scale.invert(validatedX))}`);
        d3.select(this).select("circle")
          .attr("cx", d.x = validatedX);
      })
      .on('start', function() {
        d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation()
        d3.select(this).raise()
      })
      .on('end', function({ id, x }) {
      // Here everytime settings is the initial data array and not the updated one. 
        const newSettings = settings.map(el => {
          if (el.id === id) {
            return {...el, day: Math.round(scale.invert(x))};
          }
          return el;
        });
        updateSettings(newSettings);
      });
```

It would be possible for me to update the settings array with different method and not using map, thus avoiding the problem but i guess its better to learn to solve the issue than just avoid it.

I believe that the settings data which i am iterating over is accessible through closure which was there during the initial declaration of `.call(drag)` and in result i cannot reach the fresh data.

How is it possible to access new settings data in functions?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, i solved my issue by changing a bit the code and "avoiding" my initial problem.

```
.on('end', () => {
    const nodesData = d3.selectAll('.handlersGroup').data();
    const newSettings = nodesData.map(({ x, color, type, id }) => 
      ({ color, type, id, day: Math.round(scale.invert(x)) }));

    updateSettings(newSettings);
  });
```

If anyone knows how to access the updated data directly, please post the correct solution